# Expected type 'int' but returned type 'NoneType'."

Tags: python-3.6, nonetype

I have to write a *python* function that takes two single-line strings as inputs and returns the index where the first difference between the two occurs (and a negative number in the case they're identical). This is the code I wrote so far:

```
def singleline_diff(line1, line2):
    len1 = len(line1)
    len2 = len(line2)
    if len1 < len2:
        min_len = len1
    elif len1 > len2:
        min_len = len2
    else:
        min_len = len1
    indx1 = 0
    indx2 = 0
    if line1 == line2:
        return IDENTICAL
    elif line1 != line2:
        if min_len == len1:
            for word2 in line2:
                word2 = line2 [indx2]
                indx2 = indx2+1
                if word2 not in line1:
                    diff_idx_2 = int(indx2)
                    print (diff_idx_2)
        elif min_len == len2:
            for word1 in line1:
                word1 = line1 [indx1]
                indx1=indx1+1
                if word1 not in line2:
                    diff_idx_1 = int(indx1)
                    print (diff_idx_1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def singleline_diff(line1, line2):

    min_len = min(len(line1), len(line2))
    for i in range(min_len):
        if line1[i] != line2[i]:
            return i

    if min_len == len(line1) and min_len == len(line2):
        return -1      # they're identical
    return min_len     # one of the two lines has terminated, hence they differ
```

Answer (score 1):

In the event that line1 != line2, your code prints the integer to the console instead of returning the value, which is what it should be doing according to the documentation. Try `return diff_idx_2` instead of `print(diff_idx_2)` (and the same for diff_idx_1).